# How do you access char from another function

Tags: c++, function, char

So I'm currently doing it like this:

```
char name[100];

char nama(char &name)
{
    printf(">> Name\t: %s\n",name);

    return name;
}
```

But when I want to access them in the main function, it said that it can't be accessed. And I can't just decide the name either, because it'll be accessed again and again throughout the program, in the main and in another function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you're trying to do?

Comment: There are no references in `C` Are you sure your question is not about `c++`

Comment: -1 Your code is not valid C. As a bare minimum you do need to know what language you are writing code in.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I shall edit them now

Comment: "it said that it can't be accessed" No, more detail please.

Answer (score 1):

`char nama(char &name)` should be  `char* nama(char *name)`

```
char* nama(char *name)
{
    printf(">> Name\t: %s\n",name);

    return name;
}
```

Comment: This depends if @user3087163 is using C or C++

Comment: @Sash since `name` is a char array, `char &` is very unlikely in any case.

Comment: Tried this but end up with error when I want to call the name

Comment: @user3087163 then show your calling code.

Comment: I call it in another function using this: nama(name);

Comment: @user3087163 Calling is ok. But what error you got?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x56ce14cf (msvcr100d.dll) in Fishing ovo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001. And the name that come out also become strange and not the name I put in, for example, I put in Ame, and it come out as 8q9

Comment: @user3087163 Error is some where else. Not here

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
char name[100];

char nama(char *name)
{
    printf(">> Name\t: %s\n",name);

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? `return name` will not coerce into a `char`.

Comment: I tried it and immediately meet an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code passes a single character reference to the function, not the pointer to the char array you allocated.

You should change the function signature from:

```
char nama(char &name)
```

to:

```
char nama(char *name)
```

and this should do the trick.

This tells the function that it expects a char pointer as input, which is what the %s  of printf expecting. Otherwise you are giving it different variable types than it expects, and obviously causing very undesirable behavior.